# How to get songtitle (9th element) from this json - ajax/jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, shoutcast

sample json:

```
{"currentlisteners":0,"peaklisteners":0,"maxlisteners":5,
 "uniquelisteners":0,"averagetime":0,"servergenre":"Bollywood",
 "servergenre2":"","servergenre3":"","servergenre4":"","servergenre5":"",
 "serverurl":"http:\/\/www.website.in","servertitle":"RadioName",
 "songtitle":"Udit Narayan - Bheed Mein - www.Songspk.name","dj":"encoder","songurl":"","streamhits":21514,"streamstatus":1,"backupstatus":0,"streamlisted":1,"streamsource":"203.xxx.xxx.xxx","streampath":"\/stream","streamuptime":0,"bitrate":"64","content":"audio\/mpeg","version":"2.4.7.256 (posix(linux x64))"}
```

```js
new Request.JSONP({
    url: 'http://ip:port/stats?sid=1&json=1',
    onSuccess: function(response) {
        show_response(response, $('post'));
    }
}).send();
show_response = function(obj, result) {
    $H(obj).each(function(v, k) {

        new Element('div', {
            html: v
        }).inject(result);
         
    });
    

};
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
    <div id='post'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Something like `v.songtitle`? What's the value of `v`? Or if you iterate over full object - check if `k == songtitle`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the returned object:

```
show_response = function(obj, result) {
      new Element('div', {
            html: obj.songtitle
        }).inject(result); 
};
```

See:

http://jsfiddle.net/s7trsu9r/2/

Comment: I need a help here

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access is in the object directly `result["songtitle"]`;

```
show_response = function(obj, result) {
    if (result["songtitle"]) 
       console.log(result["songtitle"]);
    else 
       console.log("no title availble");             
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

check if the key equals "songtitle"

```
new Request.JSONP({
url: 'http://ip:port/stats?sid=1&json=1',
onSuccess: function(response) {
    show_response(response, $('post'));
}
}).send();
show_response = function(obj, result) {
$H(obj).each(function(v, k) {
    if(k == 'songtitle)'{
        new Element('div', {
            html: v
        }).inject(result);
    }

});
```

};